# Showing a commutative ring with field subring has a unique ring homomorphism on polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

Consider the following problem, given without solution in a german abstract algebra text book:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $K \subseteq R$ a subring,
>   such that $1 \in K$ and $K$ is a field.
>
> Show that for each $r\in R$ there exists a unique ring homomorphism
>   $\varphi: K \left[X\right] \rightarrow R$, such that $\varphi(a) = a$
>   for $a \in K$ and $\varphi(X) = r$.
>
> $K\left[X\right]$ is the ring of all polynomials over $K$ with variable $X$.

I do not know at all about how to approach this. This is the beginning of a very introductory course on abstract algebra, and I feel like I'm missing the required tools here. How can this be proven?

Comment: Define, for $p\in K[X]$,  $\phi(p)=p(a)$ and check the definition of homomorphism.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I do not quite follow - since $a$ is not a fixed value here, how am I allowed to define $\phi$ like that without binding $a$? The only thing fixed is $r$

Comment: Yes, I wrote the wrong name. $\phi(p)=p(r)$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you, I will try that out :)

Comment: @conditionalMethod Yea, that worked. The only thing left is to show that this homomorphism is unique, which I am now stuck at. Any hints for that? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is immediate from the universal property that defines the polynomial ring.